# turning this regexp from PHP into TCL:

Tags: tcl

would appreciate if someone with far better knowledge of regexp could help me out turning this regexp from PHP into TCL:

```
preg_match('%(?:youtube(?:-nocookie)?\.com/(?:[^/]+/.+/|(?:v|e(?:mbed)?)/|.*[?&]v=)|youtu\.be/)([^"&?/ ]{11})%i', $url, $match);
```

i take it from here:

```
<?php
// Here is a sample of the URLs this regex matches: (there can be more content after the given URL that will be ignored)

// http://youtu.be/dQw4w9WgXcQ
// http://www.youtube.com/embed/dQw4w9WgXcQ
// http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ
// http://www.youtube.com/?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ
// http://www.youtube.com/v/dQw4w9WgXcQ
// http://www.youtube.com/e/dQw4w9WgXcQ
// http://www.youtube.com/user/username#p/u/11/dQw4w9WgXcQ
// http://www.youtube.com/sandalsResorts#p/c/54B8C800269D7C1B/0/dQw4w9WgXcQ
// http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=dQw4w9WgXcQ
// http://www.youtube.com/?feature=player_embedded&v=dQw4w9WgXcQ

// It also works on the youtube-nocookie.com URL with the same above options.
// It will also pull the ID from the URL in an embed code (both iframe and object tags)

preg_match('%(?:youtube(?:-nocookie)?\.com/(?:[^/]+/.+/|(?:v|e(?:mbed)?)/|.*[?&]v=)|youtu\.be/)([^"&?/ ]{11})%i', $url, $match);
$youtube_id = $match[1];
?>
```

Comment: maybe you can show us your `url`... and what you expect as a result

Comment: The RE appears to be for extracting the item token from a YouTube URL.

Comment: i take it from the last codes php i just added i want result for tls to turn in regex for tcl not php

Answer (score 1):

The Tcl and PHP RE languages are quite similar in this area (there are areas where they diverge, but this RE doesn't use them). The behaviour of using a match array in PHP is much like using the `-inline` option to `regexp` and saving the result (a list) in a variable that can then be indexed into (e.g., with `lindex`). The wrapping `%…%i` part of the PHP code becomes the `-nocase` option. Finally, you'll want to put REs in Tcl in `{`braces`}`.

```tcl
set match [regexp -inline -nocase {(?:youtube(?:-nocookie)?\.com/(?:[^/]+/.+/|(?:v|e(?:mbed)?)/|.*[?&]v=)|youtu\.be/)([^"&?/ ]{11})} $url]
#"# This line is just for the broken code highlighter here on Stack Overflow
set youtube_id [lindex $match 1]
```

We can split that into more lines for readability.

```tcl
set RE {(?:youtube(?:-nocookie)?\.com/(?:[^/]+/.+/|(?:v|e(?:mbed)?)/|.*[?&]v=)|youtu\.be/)([^"&?/ ]{11})}
#"# This line is just for the broken code highlighter here on Stack Overflow
set match [regexp -inline -nocase $RE $url]
set youtube_id [lindex $match 1]
```

The first line here is storing the regular expression in a variable, and the second line applies the RE to whatever is in the `url` variable, storing the resulting list in the `match` variable for later examination. Which is a good match for what `preg_match` was doing over in PHP.

---

Since you only actually want the ID, that's easy too:

```
set RE {(?:youtube(?:-nocookie)?\.com/(?:[^/]+/.+/|(?:v|e(?:mbed)?)/|.*[?&]v=)|youtu\.be/)([^"&?/ ]{11})}
#"# This line is just for the broken code highlighter here on Stack Overflow
regexp -nocase $RE $url --> youtube_id
```

(The `-->` is actually a dummy variable name that gets assigned the whole matched URL, but using an arrow is more mnemonic.)

Comment: If desired, you can embed the caselessness inside the RE, similar to the PHP case, by prepending `(?i)`: set RE {(?i)(?:youtube ...)}

Comment: Thx a lot guys is exatly what i was searching :)